# Flutter keyboard_actions widget area scrolling is not working

Tags: flutter, keyboard, action

My task was to add button Done to text keyboard which hides keyboard after `CupertinoTextField` is filled with value.
 I used keyboard_actions lib and it worked fine, but the area of `FormKeyboardActions()` widget became unscrollable - scrolling is broken after my implementation of 
keyboard_actions lib.

I tried to add directly `CupertinoTextField` to `FormKeyboardActions()` as a child, but it is also not working.

The code of parent PageTemplate widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    body: FormKeyboardActions(
      child: SafeArea(  //child
          child: Padding(
            padding: DesignPadding.V16__X,
            child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: this.children
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 8),
      child: this.floatingActionButton,
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  ),
 );
 }
```

The widget with CupertinoTextField:

```
class _ProductEditCommentState extends State<ProductEditComment> {
final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode(skipTraversal: true);

KeyboardActionsConfig _buildConfig(BuildContext context) {
return KeyboardActionsConfig(
  keyboardActionsPlatform: KeyboardActionsPlatform.ALL,
  keyboardBarColor: Colors.grey[200],
  nextFocus: false,
  actions: [
    KeyboardAction(
      focusNode: focusNode,
      closeWidget: Padding(
        padding: DesignPadding.V8__X,
        child: Text(
          "Done",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: DesignColors.BLACK,
            fontSize: DesignFonts.FONT_SIZE__16,
            fontFamily: DesignFonts.FONT_FAMILY__MEDIUM,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}
```

```
@override
void initState() {
 FormKeyboardActions.setKeyboardActions(context, _buildConfig(context));
 super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
 super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 ProductEditBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of(context);
 return  SingleChildScrollView(
       child: CupertinoTextField(
         focusNode: focusNode,
         maxLines: null,
         onChanged: this.widget.onChanged,
         controller: this.widget.controller,
         keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(border: null),
         textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
         placeholder: bloc.productComment == null || bloc.productComment.isEmpty
             ? "Добавить заметку"
             : bloc.productComment,
         placeholderStyle: TextStyle(
             color: DesignColors.GREY_CHROME,
             fontSize: DesignFonts.FONT_SIZE__14,
             fontFamily: DesignFonts.FONT_FAMILY__REGULAR),
         style: TextStyle(
             color: DesignColors.GREY_COAL,
             fontSize: DesignFonts.FONT_SIZE__14,
             fontFamily: DesignFonts.FONT_FAMILY__REGULAR),
         padding: EdgeInsets.only(
           left: DesignPadding.V10,
           top: DesignPadding.V14,
           bottom: DesignPadding.V20,
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
  }
```

The implementation of ProductEditComment widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return BlocProvider(
     bloc: bloc,
     child: PageTemplate( 
children: <Widget>[
    Heading(
        title: "Заметка",
        style: DesignFonts.STYLE_TITLE,
      ),
      StreamBuilder<String>(
          stream: bloc.outComment,
          initialData: this.widget.product?.comment,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ProductEditComment(
              name: snapshot.data,
              onChanged: bloc.setComment,
              controller: bloc.commentController,
            );
          }),
 ]
 )
```